# How to open folder and view properties of folder in Java?

Tags: java, file, file-io, directory, file-handling

Why `File file=new File("folderName");` doesn't work?
folder name and path is valid. Same code is running for files but not for folders.

```
File file=new File("folderName");
if(file.exists()){
 System.out.println("Folder exists");
}
else{
  System.out.println("Folder doesn't exists");
}
```

For folder `file.exists()` always return false.

I can't use other libraries in my Assignment.

Comment: It works on my system. Are you sure *folderName* is in the same directory as the program you are executing?

Comment: By the way, you can just do `if(file.exists())` checking for true is redundant

Comment: Yes I am sure. I tried for files and folder in same directory. It worked for files but didn't worked for folders. I have checked for different folders and took care of spaces in folder name.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you actually have a folder named folderName or is folderName a variable in which case it should not be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: it doesn't matter. it is here an example of my code only. I using it correctly in my code.
      `File file=new File(path);`
this is my code statement

Comment: Doesn't matter what you think is right...your code is not working and it should be and the most likely problem is the fact that your so called "correct path" is not as correct as you think! Let's see the path you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is looking for "`folderName`" in the wrong place:

```
File file = new File("folderName");
```

That uses the current working directory, and it might be different than what you assume (depending on your environment, IDE, etc).

You can easily debug the issue using:

```
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath())
```

By the way, you should simplify `if(file.exists() == true)` to `if(file.exists())`.

Comment: Is this doesn't help, some questions: is `folderName` *exactly* (case-sensitively) same as the name of the folder? What operating system are you on?

Comment: Thank You so much it solved my problem. Actually there was extra before folder name while generating its address.

Answer (score 0):

You can view all properties of folder **Managing Metadata**, which docs you can consult [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html).

You have some methods:

- size(Path).
- isDirectory(Path, LinkOption).
- isRegularFile(Path, LinkOption...).
- isSymbolicLink(Path).
- isHidden(Path).
- get/setLastModifiedTime(Path, LinkOption...).
- get/setOwner(Path, LinkOption...)
- ...

You can use those with your System.out methods or with other methods. You can read some attributes and modify your file too.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should indeed work however if you are explicitly checking for folder (directory) existence then your IF/ELSE condition should be something like this:

```
if(file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) { 
    System.out.println("Folder exists");
}
else{
  System.out.println("Folder doesn't exists");
}
```

Comment: No it is not working. Actually program says it doesn't exist.

Comment: Then..."folderName" simply doesn't exist. Is "folderName" suppose to be a variable. If it is then get rid of the quotation marks.